# Capturing and Saving an image in Android with different names and then retrieving it by any of those names?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am new to android and have managed to run my app where I can use the camera to capture the image. However I want to know the best solution to store and retrieve the images.

1. Is it good to store the images in SQLlite or External Memory
2. Can I store the image with multiple comma separated names in sqllite and then retrieve it as per those names.

For e.g. I have a capture button where I can click to capture an image and then if the image is okay i can press next where it shows me a text box and save button. In the text box I can enter multiple  names of image say - x1, x2, x3 etc. and then i want to retrieve the image by using any of these names.

any good idea will be much appreciated.

Comment: you can try SharedPreferences if it just simple data. and use sqlite database if more complex. store image on external

Answer (score 2):

I think best way to store your Images is to save it on External memory. This way is also simplest way!

Here you are some pice of code to save the image on external

```
public static File saveImage(Bitmap bitmap, String imageName) {
        File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), DIR);

        if (!myDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.e(ImageUtils.class.getSimpleName(), "Directory not created");
        }

        myDir.mkdirs();
        String image = getImageName(imageName);
        File file = new File(myDir, image);

        if (file.exists())
            return null;
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            return file;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I hope that it will be usefull for you

Comment: Thanks markView. but can we save the image with multiple names using this techinque. I thought if i use sqllite I can have the image names mapped to single image and then can query based on image name.