# How should images be manages in Android when not through SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-image

I have some entities which I hold in `SQLite DB`.
Some of these entities will have image as well, as I read, SQLite DB can return up to 2MB per cursor, so storing the images in the DB isn't an option.
So I guess we are left with internal storage and self managing.
Are there any support libraries for managing these images ?
Is there a recommended design for this ?
I though about saving the images with a filename scheme of `entityType_id.png` where the id is the entity id in the SQLite DB, but I'm afraid it may change over time (backup / restore and such) so maybe another scheme might be a better solution ?

Comment: How would you manage any files 'out of' sqlite?

Comment: @user2864740 as I mentioned, SQLite cursor is limited for 2MB while I want to store files larger than that.

Comment: As asked, how would you store any files outside of sqlite?

Answer (score 1):

I used the solution that you mentioned here:

> I though about saving the images with a filename scheme of entityType_id.png where the id is the entity id in the SQLite DB, but I'm afraid it may change over time (backup / restore and such) so maybe another scheme might be a better solution ?

I created a folder in my Android project and used ids that will never change. Knowing the folder and the id, which I retrieve from the DB, I am able to get the image. I used the [android SQLite asset helper library](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for the solution.

I used such an approach for this little app: [MTBcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sixtytwentypeaks.mtbcat). You can find an example here: http://www.6020peaks.com/2015/03/how-to-ship-an-android-app-with-preloaded-data/

Comment: Looks nice.. I believe I'll have to make sure the ID's will never change before using them for the filename scheme, but it looks like I'm on the right track..

Answer (score 1):

You should store all of images on the internal storage. There is a post about that with piece of code, which could be helpful for you:

[Capturing and Saving an image in Android with different names and then retrieving it by any of those names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713542/capturing-and-saving-an-image-in-android-with-different-names-and-then-retrievin/32714507#32714507)

EDIT:
I mean external storange not internal

Comment: Thanks, notice the answer in your link suggests using external storage and not internal, personally I disagree.

Comment: Sory, that was a typo.

Comment: Can you please specify why one should prefer external over internal ?

Comment: I think that the more important thing is to store images outside of your app local database because of the restriction (e.g. SQLite files restriction). Another thing is that keeping the images on external storage is good practice

Comment: Why would you store the images in the external storage? Can you explain the advantage of doing so, if any exists?

Answer (score 0):

Have some sequence to generate unique ids (maybe just store current value as property), and store the id only in the database. Name the image file by id and store the file somewhere in the file system. If you delete the record, remove the file and do not reuse the id.

Generate own ids, independent from what the database is doing. Then they will not be affected by backup/restore or things the like.

Answer (score -2):

I think storing an image which size is more than 2M in sqlite is not good for reading or whiting,maybe you can compress your image before you store it.

Comment: Compression is possible, in the price of losing image quality of course.  Anyway, 2MB isn't enough..